# how to check the status of the UPI payment using the UPI ID

Tags: android, spring, upi

is there a way to check the current status of the upi payment using the **UPI Transaction Id**. is there some **API** available for that purpose ?
i just want to confirm whether the payment is done from the web service using the Transaction Id.

-Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Some banks provide developer API to check status. But really UPI seems to be a bank to bank transfer. So you need to be account holder in one of those banks who have an API. I am using ICICI bank currently.